# How to delete current (this) divs in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Look at this example - http://jsfiddle.net/s11Lbnp8/1/`

I have in rails app dynamic added post-wrap. And when i click delete, need to remove only this wrap, which button i clicked. I try everything (closest, childred, parent) and other, but... i`am stuck. Help.

```
<div class="post-wrap">
            <hr>
            <small>Отправлено 123в</small>
            <img class="img-responsive thumbnail user-image-home" src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/225/8/d/render_anime_girl__3_by_angietmnt-d6i0np2.png" alt="14243167476560">
            <p class="text-content">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
            <small class="text-muted">Добавлено 10 minutes назад</small>
            <br>
            <a data-confirm-button-text="Удалить" data-cancel-button-text="Нет" data-sweet-alert-type="warning" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="wow" data-sweet-alert-confirm="Удалить?" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/posts/44">Удалить</a>
            <hr>
          </div>
                <div class="post-wrap">
            <hr>
            <small>Отправлено 123в</small>
            <img class="img-responsive thumbnail user-image-home" src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/225/8/d/render_anime_girl__3_by_angietmnt-d6i0np2.png" alt="14243167476560">
            <p class="text-content">eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</p>
            <small class="text-muted">Добавлено 10 minutes назад</small>
            <br>
            <a data-confirm-button-text="Удалить" data-cancel-button-text="Нет" data-sweet-alert-type="warning" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="wow" data-sweet-alert-confirm="Удалить?" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/posts/44">Удалить</a>
            <hr>
          </div>
```

> $(".post-wrap", this).remove();

Comment: where is your delete click handler

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9zcgw4qj/1/ - but I doubt your callback is as simple because you have the confirmation dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this http://jsbin.com/marilapune/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
$(".post-wrap .btn").click(function(){

  $(this).parents('.post-wrap').remove();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.closest('div')` or `.parent()` along with current elements context to traverse to parent div element and then remove it:

```
$('[data-method="delete"]').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s11Lbnp8/2/)

Try this

```
$(".post-wrap").on("click", function () {
                   $(this).remove();
 });
```